# Quartz Plugin Error in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I use the Grails [Quartz](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) and get the following error while running:

```
| Error 2013-11-25 16:38:34,701 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailPersistenceService$_selectMessagesIdsForSend_closure1
   Line | Method
->> 111 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   202 | run     in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run . . in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailPersistenceService$_selectMessagesIdsForSend_closure1
->>  20 | selectMessagesIdsForSend in grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailPersistenceService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    18 | findAndSendEmails in grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailProcessService
|    19 | execute in grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailJob
|   104 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
|   202 | run . . in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run     in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
```

**How can I avoid this error?**

Edit: Grails version 2.2.4

Comment: It seems that you use AsynchronousMailJob from another plugin. Are you use async mail plugin?

Comment: @baxxabit yes I use this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail

Comment: @baxxabit does it cause any problems in combination?

Comment: I haven't experience with async mail plugin, but you can create an issue in github repo, author of plugin can answer you. Author of async email plugin is a contributor for quartz @confile

Comment: What version of grails do you use?

Comment: @baxxabit Grails 2.2.4

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you get any resolution for this?